# Is there any way accessing shifted matrix of a ComplexHeatmap?

Tags: r

I would like to draw a very huge heatmap by the great-great ComplexHeatmap library.

The initial matrix has more than 2000 rows and 50+ columns with integer values running from -3 to +3.

I encountered the *Error: C stack usage is too close to the limit* issue immediately - this might be the limitation of the underlying recursive (?) algorithm.

I found the `jitter` parameter as a solution - after some struggling with `prlimit` and `ulimit` stack adjustment.

So everything is *almost* ok now:

`jitter` parameter randomizing the clustering by rows per each execution.
So it is hard to check consistency of the resulted heatmaps in my pipeline.
I realized that I can access the input matrix.
For example:

```r
hm <- Heatmap(input_matrix,
    name = "Monstre Heatmap etc.",
    # ... long parameter list ...
    show_row_dend = TRUE,
    jitter = TRUE,
    # ... further parameters
)
> # accessing the inner data and compare with the input:
> identical(input_matrix, hm@matrix)
[1] TRUE
```

Is there any field to expose the *shifted matrix* in heatmap object?

Comment: Can you check whether hm@matrix remains identical when you set a seed (e.g. `set.seed(123)`) before running the `Heatmap` function? You might at least be able to get a reproducible jitter... but I found no issue when generating a 20000 x 50 matrix with 50% identical rows or columns with `jitter = FALSE`, so I am not sure your stack issues are directly caused by this. Do you have `fastcluster` installed?

Comment: As I see `set.seed` solved the consistency issue. :-) Thank you very much!

Comment: I wanted to manipulate the input matrix by the function's jitter calculation (then keep the matrix in my .RData and load it for each reproduction):

`mat = mat + runif(length(mat), min = 0, max = 1e-10)`
https://github.com/jokergoo/ComplexHeatmap/blob/2a95cb66786a595c28ce2992992eb415a36fc03f/R/Heatmap-class.R#L1036

Comment: @user12728748: How can I accept your answer? (since it is just a comment)

Btw. I have no `fastcluster` on my `.libPaths()`. Why does it matter? Would be better to do the clustering by it? Or:  can `ComplexHeatmap` use it? - if it is installed

Comment: Yes, it can use it, and it is faster (doh), and might use less memory, hence you may not even get the memory error... worth a try.

Comment: @user12728748 Thank you. I will try it - maybe it can eliminate the jitter-caused value updates (now my legend is from -4 to +4 instead of -3 to +3).

Comment: @user12728748 Can you write your answer's summary below as an answer and not as a comment? I don't know how I can close this question with just comments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per request, this is reiterating my comments above:

The jitter introduced in the `Heatmap` function when you set `jitter = TRUE` can be kept reproducible when you set a fixed random seed prior to running the function, e.g. `set.seed(123)`.
If `jitter = TRUE`, random values from uniform distribution between 0 and 1e-10 are generated, as per the `Heatmap` documentation, so you could probably just introduce jitter into the matrix yourself (using a defined random seed), prior to running `Heatmap` and get the same result, such as:

`input_matrix <- input_matrix + runif(length(input_matrix), 0, 1e-10)`,
as you mentioned yourself already.

Regarding the memory issue, you may try to install and use `fastcluster`, which is a drop-in replacement for `hclust` which is faster and may consume less memory.

For ComplexHeatmap to use it, it may be necessary to run `ht_opt("fast_hclust" = TRUE)` prior to running `Heatmap`. To reset to defaults, use `ht_opt(RESET = TRUE)`.

Concerning the legend, you can configure the limits of the color legend yourself (see: https://jokergoo.github.io/ComplexHeatmap-reference/book/legends.html)

As a side note, I found no issue when generating a 20000 x 50 matrix with 50% identical rows or columns with jitter = FALSE, so I am not sure your stack issues are directly caused by this.

Comment: Thank you for this great summary!